# debian добавление самоподписного сертификата в доверенные

Tags: linux, debian, certificate

Я для целей проксирования nginx создал самоподписной сертификат по аналогии с данной [инструкцией](https://www.humankode.com/ssl/create-a-selfsigned-certificate-for-nginx-in-5-minutes/):

Добавил его в nginx, затем попробовал добавить в список доверенных:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo/
sudo cp ./localhost.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo/localhost.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

на выходе получил сообщение об успешном обновлении CA хранилища. Однако когда захожу по проксируемому пути,вижу сертификат, однако он помечен как опасный (т.е. в список доверенных не добавился).

Ошибка : NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 3):

Две ошибки и маленькое замечание.

Хром не использует системные сертификаты. Установите через chrome://settings/certificates

Subject стоит localhost, обращаетесь к 127.0.0.1 - это не одно и тоже.

Судя по маленькому PEM - у вас там один сертификат в цепочке. Сделайте нормальную цепочку `CA->SubCA->Site`. Через easy-rsa или xca.

Comment: мне для тестов разве одного сертификата не будет достаточно ?

обращаюсь к localhost - та же проблема. в списке имен сайтов сертификата указан как порт, так и локалхост.

Comment: Получается что файр фокс тоже не использует системные сертификаты? там та же проблема

Comment: установите сертификат в хром в раздел серверы

Comment: по умолчанию тоже не использует системные сертификаты https://support.mozilla.org/ru/kb/nastrojka-centrov-sertifikacii-ca-v-firefox